# threejs moving one object moves the second too

Tags: three.js

I'm new at three.js and i need to load a particle object
it seems to work if add particles on vertices

if i load my Json once and inside the load() i build 2 different THREE.Points when i mov the first the second also move if i use 2 different load calls and inside each i build a THREE.Points object each object can be move separately

this i the function that i call inside animate

```
function animateParticles( particleSystem, particleSystemOriginal, deltaTime ) {

    var vertsOriginal = particleSystemOriginal.geometry.vertices;
    var verts = particleSystem.geometry.vertices;       

    for(var i = 0; i < verts.length; i++) {

        var vertOriginal = vertsOriginal[i]; // original position
        var vert = verts[i]; // cloud position

        var vertOriginalY = vertOriginal.y;         
        var vertY = vert.y;

        if (i==1) console.log("vertOriginalY " + vertOriginalY + " vertY " + vertY);

        vert.y = vertY - (10 * deltaTime); // move          

    }

    particleSystemOriginal.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    particleSystem.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

}
```

it seems strange that i need to load twice the same object to move one of them

in my function i'just testing and moving dove the cloud but what i would like is to shake particles, so i need to know particles original position and set particles new position

EDIT 1

i load my model like this

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(); 
loader.load('../3d-models/creati/mymodel-001.json', function(geometry, materials) {

    var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial(); 
    var particleModelOriginal = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    var particleModel = particleModelOriginal.clone();

    /* build particle THREE.Points */

    particleSystemOriginal = new THREE.Points(particlesOriginal, particleMaterial);     
    particleSystem = new THREE.Points(particles, particleMaterial);
    //particleSystem = particleSystemOriginal.clone();

 });
```

Comment: could you also include how you load the object?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you probably need to use the `.clone()` object on mesh/geometry that you are loading if you want to create multiple objects. Otherwise they are referencing the same object, and will both be modified if one of them are modified

Comment: I edit my question on EDIT 1 they both move tougher either if i clone my mash after loading or i clone my cloud at the end